# It's possible to show my notifacation bar and title bar while ontouch?

Tags: android

I hid my notification bar and title bar using below code. But Now, I want to create this notification bar and title bar in response to touch. If I touch my emulator screen, I want to show my notification and title bar after automatically hiding them when I touched that time only I need this notification and title bar that's all.

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This is my xml file.....
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/videoGrdVw" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:spacing="60px"
    android:background="@drawable/bk1"
    />
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="100px" 
    android:id="@+id/Header" 
    android:background="@drawable/images1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

</LinearLayout> 
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="100px" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/images2" 
    android:id="@+id/Footer" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
 </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an onTouchListener on your main layout element.

This will:

- Allow you to capture touch events for the entire portion of the screen your application occupies
- Detect DOWN and UP touch events

Something like this would work:

```
mainlayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              //Code to ENABLE titlebar
          }
          else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
               //Code to DISABLE titlebar
          }
          return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: now i am updated my question.....am using this way setContentView(R.layout.main); then how to use this code.....

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking?